# Can't access Private Nuget on OSX Catalina

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, nuget, macos-catalina

We use a private nuget repo, via a VPN,  (hosted on local TFS) and since one of the recent Calalina upgrades, I can no longer connect to the feed.

I keep getting repeatedly asked for my credentials.  I have tried inputting them in format of either *domain\username* and *username@company.com* but they don't work.  I have also tried using a Personal Access token too, but get the same issue.

I can access the nugget feed from windows or the TFS Portal without any problems.

TFS Version 16.131.28106.2

Comment: What is the error message when you use the PAT to access it?

Comment: Hi @Ashley Jackson, could you please share the error message here? If the error code is 401, this is related to your account permissions. If you get error code are 403 or others, you need check your VPN and Firewall setting.